# Sync Two SharePoint Lists

Tags: list, sync

I have one list, call it List A, and I want to create a new list, List B, that has all the same fields as List A with some additions. List B will be edited at a later time, but I want it to be updated every time a new item is created/edited in List A. What is the best way that I can synchronize two separate lists in SharePoint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Their are couple of ways you can do it.

1. Create a workflow which update the list b on the event of add or update or delete item in List A. Check this for more info: http://www.hexanes.com/?p=897
2. use 3rd party add on, try this one [SharePoint List Sync](http://www.boostsolutions.com/list-sync.html)
3. try to create an event handler, check this example: http://sharepointchic.blogspot.com/2010/12/synchronize-lists-in-two-different-site.html